# Can a laptop be used as second monitor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, laptop-display

I have two systems, a Ubuntu PC and a Ubuntu laptop. I wonder if there is any way (wireless) to use my laptop as a second display? Because my laptop is too slow nowadays.

Comment: Not sure if it can display via WiFi, but some other possible uses: WiFi and/or file-based player, file server, photo display or donate to elder or to student who needs to connect remotely (Zoom can run on Linux).

Comment: Unfurtunatly, this isn't the answer that can help me. By the way, thanks for help.

Comment: it may be better to ask on [askubuntu.se]: [Use laptop as a second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/q/1079015/253474), [Use ubuntu laptop as external screen for windows PC](https://askubuntu.com/q/817099/253474), [Use Ubuntu 18.04 laptop as second monitor for Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1239794/253474)

Comment: Does [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-an-old-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-Ubuntu) help?